# Strange "The Incutio XML-RPC PHP Library -- WordPress/4.8" record in the access log

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

When I check my nginx access.log, the following request periodically comes in.
Why is this request coming to me? Do you have any idea what is going on?

PS: I use wordpress

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2017:17:25:49 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12124 "http://127.0.01/" "The Incutio XML-RPC PHP Library -- WordPress/4.8"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2017:17:25:49 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12124 "http://127.0.01/" "The Incutio XML-RPC PHP Library -- WordPress/4.8"
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Incutio XML-RPC PHP Library -- WordPress/4.8

This part of the access logs is the ["User agent" field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). Browsers usually put their name, version number and operating system in there. It can be spoofed by anyone.

In your case, it's http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/ which is part of Wordpress' core - see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/incutio-xml-rpc-library-causing-memory-crashes-on-the-server/

It is used to send [Pingbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback) to your site.

So probably someone linked to your site in a blog post, and her wordpress instance wanted to notify you about that.